# Datatables + JSON + best_in_place

Tags: ruby-on-rails, datatables, best-in-place

I can not add gem best_in_place to my table.

class_datatable.rb:

```
  def data
    class.map do |record|
      [
        best_in_place(record, :name),
        best_in_place(record, :short_name)
      ]
    end
  end
```

There is an error: NoMethodError (undefined method `best_in_place' for ClassDatatable:0xa9283a44)

My gem file:
    source 'https://rubygems.org'

```
# Bundle edge Rails instead: gem 'rails', github: 'rails/rails'
gem 'rails', '4.2.4'
# Use sqlite3 as the database for Active Record
gem 'ruby-oci8'
gem 'activerecord-oracle_enhanced-adapter'
# Use SCSS for stylesheets
gem 'sass-rails', '~> 5.0'
# Use Uglifier as compressor for JavaScript assets
gem 'uglifier', '>= 1.3.0'
# Use CoffeeScript for .coffee assets and views
gem 'coffee-rails', '~> 4.1.0'
# See https://github.com/rails/execjs#readme for more supported runtimes
# gem 'therubyracer', platforms: :ruby

# Use jquery as the JavaScript library
gem 'jquery-rails'
gem 'jquery-turbolinks'
# Turbolinks makes following links in your web application faster. Read more: https://github.com/rails/turbolinks
gem 'turbolinks'
# Build JSON APIs with ease. Read more: https://github.com/rails/jbuilder
gem 'jbuilder', '~> 2.0'
# bundle exec rake doc:rails generates the API under doc/api.
gem 'sdoc', '~> 0.4.0', group: :doc

# Use ActiveModel has_secure_password
# gem 'bcrypt', '~> 3.1.7'

# Use Unicorn as the app server
# gem 'unicorn'

# Use Capistrano for deployment
# gem 'capistrano-rails', group: :development

#---------------------------------My gems--------------------------------------------------------
#Twitter Bootstrap
gem "therubyracer"
gem "less-rails" #Sprockets (what Rails 3.1 uses for its asset pipeline) supports LESS
gem "twitter-bootstrap-rails"
gem 'client_side_validations'

#Datatables
gem 'jquery-datatables-rails', '~> 1.12.2'
gem 'font-awesome-rails'          # Icons 
gem 'foundation-rails'            # zurb foundation 

#Best in place
gem 'best_in_place'

#Russian langue
gem 'russian', '~> 0.6.0'

#Jquery UI
gem 'jquery-ui-rails'

#Paginate
gem 'will_paginate'

#-----------------------------------end---------------------------------------------------------
group :development, :test do
  # Call 'byebug' anywhere in the code to stop execution and get a debugger console
  gem 'byebug'
end

group :development do
  # Access an IRB console on exception pages or by using <%= console %> in views
  gem 'web-console', '~> 2.0'

  # Spring speeds up development by keeping your application running in the background. Read more: https://github.com/rails/spring
  gem 'spring'
end
```

Bundle install is done!

If I do like this on the page:

```
<% Class.all.each do |record| %>
  <%= best_in_place(record, :name) %>
<% end %>
```

That works.
However, the method does not work "def data"

Comment: u need to show gemfile

Comment: Have you done `bundle install` ?

Comment: And as I said in appliction.js line // = require best_in_place

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Understood!
It was necessary to add delegate best_in_place section at the beginning of the file class_datatable.rb

Answer (score 0):

For anyone struggling to find the right way to delegate, this is how it is done:

```
class MyCustomDatatable < AjaxDatatablesRails::Base
  # either define them one-by-one
  def_delegator :@view, :link_to
  def_delegator :@view, :h
  def_delegator :@view, :mail_to

  # or define them in one pass
  def_delegators :@view, :link_to, :h, :mailto, :edit_resource_path, :other_method

  # now, you'll have these methods available to be used anywhere
  # example: mapping the 2d jsonified array returned.
  def data
    records.map do |record|
      [
        link_to(record.fname, edit_resource_path(record)),
        mail_to(record.email),
        # other attributes
      ]
    end
  end
end
```

Source:  https://github.com/antillas21/ajax-datatables-rails#using-view-helpers